# indexing updated log lines in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have use logstash file input for getting logs indexed to elastic search and then to kibana.
I used grok filter to get some field and getting proper data but when I update the log file that is adding few lines in existing file. Logstash scanning that file from first line. I want only updated lines not already scanned lines
<>

```
input{
   file {
        path => ""
        codec => multiline{
                 pattern => "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
                 negate => true
             what => "previous"
      }
   }
}
filter{
      grok{
          match => {"message" => "(?<time_stamp>[\d\-\s\:\,]*)\s%{WORD:log_level}\s%{JAVACLASS:class}\s(\[%{DATA:thread}\])\s+(?<msg>(.|\r\n)*)"}
   }
   mutate{
      copy => {"msg" => "message"}
}
   grok{
    match => {"path" => "(?<index_name>[^\\/]+?(?=\.\w+$))"}
   }
}
output{
     stdout{
        codec => rubydebug
   }
   elasticsearch{
     hosts => ["hhtp://*.*.*.*:9200/"]
     index => ""

}
}
```

Comment: Please update post with your logstash configuration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to read just updates from files. This can be achieve with [`tail`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.x/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tail_mode) mode in logstash.

> In this mode the plugin aims to track changing files and emit new content as it’s appended to each file.

Besides that, you have option to choose to start from `beginning` or `end` in case you're using `tail` mode, more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.x/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position).

Progress of `tail` mode is saved to sincedb file in case logstash or machine is restarted it will continue from the last processed record.

Comment: it is taking at first save but after few mins it is scanning from first

Comment: That is definitely not how it should work normally, but you're not providing enough information for us to help you.

Comment: check post I have code the confi file hope that will enough